# jQuery UI Sortable is extremely laggy/unresponsive (all browsers)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a sortable list with the jquery ui sortable function. It is functioning extremely unresponsive on this site, however i have used it with identical markup in the past and experienced no problems.  Here is my markup:

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group ui-sortable">
        <div class="list-group-item" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
                <a href="/rob/roar/admin/subcategory/1/25/30"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span> category two</a>
                <form class="hidden form-horizontal" action="/rob/roar/admin/editcategory">
                    <input type="text" name="categoryname" value="category two">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 text-right">
                <button class="btn delete admin-title" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="" data-content="<center><a class='confirm-delete' href='/rob/roar/admin/deletecategory/30'>Yes</a></center>" data-original-title="Are you sure you want to delete?"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="list-group-item" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
                <a href="/rob/roar/admin/subcategory/1/26/31"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span> test</a>
                <form class="hidden form-horizontal" action="/rob/roar/admin/editcategory">
                    <input type="text" name="categoryname" value="test">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 text-right">
                <button class="btn delete admin-title" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="" data-content="<center><a class='confirm-delete' href='/rob/roar/admin/deletecategory/31'>Yes</a></center>" data-original-title="Are you sure you want to delete?"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
                <a href="/rob/roar/admin/subcategory/1/1/1"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span> Administration</a>
                <form class="hidden form-horizontal" action="/rob/roar/admin/editcategory">
                    <input type="text" name="categoryname" value="Administration">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 text-right">
                <button class="btn delete admin-title" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="" data-content="<center><a class='confirm-delete' href='/rob/roar/admin/deletecategory/1'>Yes</a></center>" data-original-title="Are you sure you want to delete?"><span class="fa fa-times"></span> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Javascript (easy enough):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-group').disableSelection();
    $('.list-group').sortable();
});
```

My initial thought was all the hidden forms and the popover inside the elements causing some kind of bizarre lag, but removing all of those and trying it plain still caused the issue.

Below is a gif of the lag in action

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nduqyzur/1/)

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can't recreate problem... http://jsfiddle.net/nduqyzur/

Comment: @nevermind your fiddle doesn't look like working at all :)

Comment: @webeno, actually, it is working fine, try to select div, and replace it. ;)

Comment: @nevermind interesting, http://jsfiddle.net/nduqyzur/1/ -- adding bootstrap files did nothing, then adding all of my separate CSS caused the lag to start again. something in there must be causing it

Comment: @robz228, ok, so, now you located problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: isn't it `.list-group-item` that's set to `transition: 400ms;`...?

Comment: ...try it now: http://jsfiddle.net/nduqyzur/2/

Comment: @webeno makes sense! beautiful!! submit answer so i can accept it? thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by `.list-group-item` that's set to `transition: 400ms;`.

```
.list-group-item {
  transition: 400ms;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

Removing it will remove the lag: http://jsfiddle.net/nduqyzur/2/